# Capturing user information for S3 upload from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I need to upload a file via browser to an S3 bucket - this will be via an authenticated application.

Is there anyway to capture the details of the authenticated user who uploads the file from AWS - say in an S3 event, or encoding meta-data and associating it with the file via the upload?

Ideally, I'd like to pass the data via an SQS message along with the upload notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your custom metadata (user info) on an S3 object. Read the "User-Defined Metadata" section [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata).

After that you could configure S3 to insert an event message into an SQS queue, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html).

Comment: Thanks Mark B for your comment, but I have one question. In the documentation doesn't explain how to take the metadata added to the file uploaded and send it inside the event to SQS. Do you have any idea how to do that?